# Invalid initial cursor position inside input text with padding in IE8

Tags: input, internet-explorer-8, padding

My problem was already described here: 
http://the-dees.webs.com/iepp1/45-input-padding.html
but no solution or work-around was provided.

Problem: if you have input text with padding in IE8, the initial position of text and the blinking cursor is invalid (it's rendered at the top of the input). Once you start typing, text and cursor move to the proper position (the middle of the input).

Input is only styled with following:

```
input {
   padding: 10px 0;
}
```

I've found a workaround, which is unacceptable for me. Namely, if I remove left or right padding (or both), everything looks fine:

```
input {
   padding-top: 10px;
   padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

However, if you don't declare padding-left or padding-right to be zero, then IE may give a weird default value (in my case it was 1px)

Interestingly, this problem appears only in plain IE8 and in IE9 with IE8 document mode. It does **not** appear in IE7, IE9, IE10 or IE10 with IE8 document mode.

How can this problem be solved?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the [`line-height`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_line-height.asp) property on `input` will fix the position of the text and caret.